# Can't change date format SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, exasol

I have the current date format [DD_MM_YYY] in a column on my table and would like to change it to [YYYY_MM_DD]. Can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: your current date format datatype is date of varchar ?

Answer (score 0):

This one should do for date fields:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the convert function in sql.

```
SELECT CONVERT (data_type(length)),Date, DateFormatCode)
```

To convert in this format [YYYY_MM_DD] if the date format is in `varchar`:

```
Select CONVERT(varchar,column_name,23)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Exasol, you can use `to_date()`:

```
select to_date(datecoll, 'DD_MM_YYYY')
```

I would recommend leaving this as a date.  But if you want to convert this back to a string:

```
select to_char(to_date(datecoll, 'DD_MM_YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```